# Laravel получение файла из Storage

Tags: laravel, storage

Всем привет. Не понимаю, как реализовать загрузку файла через `Storage` в Laravel. Есть следующий метод в контроллере:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $manager = new Manager;
    $manager->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $manager->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $manager->phone = $request->phone;
    $manager->email = $request->email;
    $manager->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $manager->save();
    Storage::putFileAs('managers', $request->photo, $manager->id.'.'.$request->photo->getClientOriginalExtension());
    return redirect()->route('managers.index')->with('success', 'Менеджер успешно создан');   
}
```

Изображение создается в `storage/managers`, но не понимаю, как его получить пользователю через `<img>`?

Comment: `echo asset('storage/image.png');`

Answer (score 1):

можно вывести сразу в блейд с названием папки и файла

```
<img src="{{ Storage::path('directory/file.jpg') }}" />
```